# Can someone explain this little code snippet for me?

Tags: sage

I'm working on a project where I'm referencing a Maths textbook which makes use of SageMath, they've given this as a proof. I'm not well-versed in SageMath so I'm having trouble properly understand what the code is doing. Could someone explain it to me?

The theorem it's meant to be proving is the following:
"For the Hungarian Rings
puzzle every permutation of the 38 pieces is possible. In other words, HR = S38."

```
sage: S38=SymmetricGroup(38)
sage: L=S38("(1,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2)")
sage: R=S38(" (1,38,37,36,35,6,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21)")
sage: HR=S38.subgroup([L,R])
sage: HR==SymmetricGroup(38)
True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotation, though I don't know this puzzle.  Perhaps it's in David Joyner's [Adventures in Group Theory](https://jhupbooks.press.jhu.edu/title/adventures-group-theory)?

```
sage: S38=SymmetricGroup(38)
```

This is the symmetric group of all permutations of some set of 38 objects.  I hope there are 38 things in the puzzle somehow.

```
sage: L=S38("(1,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2)")
sage: R=S38(" (1,38,37,36,35,6,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21)")
```

These are two very specific permutations of the 38 objects.  Note that not all of them are permuted in each element.  Looks like between the two of them all of them are shifted by one element in either direction.  Maybe some objects go in a circle, and the others also do. Only one element in common.

```
sage: HR=S38.subgroup([L,R])
```

This is the subset (and hence subgroup) of permutations generated by doing these two ones again and again and again ...

```
sage: HR==SymmetricGroup(38)
True
```

Apparently every permutation of the 38 elements - shuttling the various objects around without reference to the actual puzzle, as if you took it completely apart - are actually achievable by just doing the two actions `L` and `R` again and again in SOME order!

That is actually pretty cool.  Now I want to find out about and play this puzzle.

Comment: Thank you! that was really helpful! That code snippet is taken from this book (http://www.sfu.ca/~jtmulhol/math302/notes/302notes.pdf) and it's the chapter on the hungarian rings puzzle. It's two interlocking circles made up of balls that you have to sort. I've been working on a functional programming algorithm to solve it! but it's a really cool puzzle and I defo recommend it!

Comment: Great!  By the way, those resources look like they are BEGGING for live Sage examples that https://pretextbook.org can provide, since the instructor is posting them freely anyway - you should let the teacher know about it!